# Status 419 on laravel project with Load Balancer

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, load-balancing, digital-ocean, http-status-codes

I'm using Digital Ocean Load balancer to divide all the requests into 2 separated servers. Both servers are runing the same Laravel application, but when those 2 servers are online and i try to do a post request, sometimes i receive a status 419 and sometimes 200, but when 1 server is offline, the requests works normally

Comment: Make sure your load balancer knows what user (or more specifically session) it needs to send to what server. Laravel uses crsf protection which is based on the users session. If your second request goes to a different server this crsf token will be invalid thus returning the 419 error

Comment: Thanks, i changed the session driver to Database and it worked :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose you are using the default session driver, which is files. Because of this your sessions are set on one of the server and the other server doesn't know of this session. The csrf token set on the form is created and checked using the current session for the visitor, if this request is posted to the other server you will receive an error 419 because this server has no knowledge of the session.

To solve this, you should use a session driver that can be shared between servers like `database`, `memcached` or `redis`.

Comment: Nice, i will try this :)

Comment: Had the same problem, just wanted to add that `cookie` works also, but you will need the same `APP_KEY` for all applications